# Rails Way to handle action that's available on multiple routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, design-patterns

I have the following routes:

```
resources :users do
  # List reviews made by user
  resources :reviews, :only => [ :index ]
end

resources :products do
  # List reviews by product, and provide :product_id for creation
  resources :reviews, :only => [ :index, :new, :create ]
end

# Other actions don't depend on other resources
resources :reviews, :except => [ :index, :new, :create ]
```

Everything looks right, except `ReviewsController#index`:

```
def index
  if params[:user_id]
    @reviews = Review.find_all_by_user_id params[:user_id]
  else
    @reviews = Review.find_all_by_product_id params[:product_id]
  end
  respond_with @reviews
end
```

I was wondering if there's a standard solution to the problem above, or if there is a better way to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you have there is fine, but if you want you can use two different actions as well. This approach should allow you to more easily change the view later on, and is a bit safer.

```
match '/products/:product_id/reviews' => 'reviews#product_index'
match '/users/:user_id/reviews' => 'reviews#user_index'
```

It will also keep your controller code a little cleaner and less susceptible to odd queries like `/products/10/reviews?user_id=100` which would result in the user's reviews being shown instead of the product's reviews.

```
def product_index
  @reviews = Review.find_all_by_product_id params[:product_id]
  respond_with @reviews
end

def user_index
  @reviews = Review.find_all_by_user_id params[:user_id]
  respond_with @reviews
end
```

The other alternative is to use different controllers as well:

```
match '/products/:product_id/reviews' => 'product_reviews#index'
match '/users/:user_id/reviews' => 'user_reviews#index'
```

Comment: Very nice suggestion. I think I should get rid of my `stick to RESTful actions` mentality. :)

Comment: Sometimes it works, other times it just gets in the way. If you do want to stick to fully restful actions, you can overwrite the controller than handles them as well, so you can have a restful ProductReviewsController and a restful UserReviewsController. Of course you are already using lots of except and only statements so using explicit url matches, like my example, might be the best solution for you.

Comment: I've heard some get too wrapped up in rest, and I agree that sometimes you need to break out, but this does not look like such a time. Actually, by making two controllers, you are breaking into the rest style, of two resources (only the index action).  In this case, I'd keep it in one controller and load appropriate to the params.

Answer (score 1):

Some plugins have ways to load resources for you, such as declarative_authorization or cancan, I'm sure there are others.

Other solutions I have seen is to make a private method in the controller to load the object, and in that method is essentially the same logic you have here; it just moves it out of the index action itself.   The metod can also then be called as a before filter.

One other way to do your logic is to start with the parent object (nice if you need the parent object too:

```
before_filter :load_collection, :only => :index

private
def load_collection
  if params[:user_id]
    @user = @parent = User.find(params[:user_id])
  else
    @product = @parent = Product.find(params[:product_id])
  end
  @reviews = @parent.reviews
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def index
  key = [:user_id, :product_id].find{|k| params[k]}
  @reviews = Review.where(key => params[key]).first
  respond_with @reviews
end
```

Comment: Why `.first`? That'll give you just one review. This also doesn't handle for polymorphic associations that reviews must have.